# NodeJS TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I just started using NodeJs still have a lot to learn but am loving it so far I ran into this problem I found an answer, but it's not what I want it's kinda weird, let me show some code and explain

So I got 2 files

File 1 > app.js (Main)

File 2 > UserEntity.js (Module)

app.js:

```
var uEntity = require('./UserEntity.js');

var hm = new uEntity.person();
console.log(hm.info.strUsername);
```

UserEntity.js:

```
function User() {
    this.info = {
        'strUsername': 'Hashimoro'
    };
}

module.exports.person = User;
```

I am creating a new UserEntity I want to access the info directly as you can see from the code

But it gives this error:

```
console.log(hm.info.strUsername);
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'strUsername' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeLearn\Testing\app.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

If someone can give a fix and explain would be great

Thank you, seriously appreciate it

Comment: What is the node version that you are using? This works for me and I have the expected result.

Comment: So you have a file called `app.js` and another called `App.js` ?

Comment: I am using the latest LTS 6.9.1, No i have only one app.js

Comment: Works for me, too. No issue can't be seen.

Comment: The sayHello() works, I am trying to access it directly 2 answer's have be given and awesomely explained :)

Comment: Make sure you have putted file on same location when you trying to accessing like **var uEntity = require('./UserEntity.js');** . if you **UserEntity.js** file inside module directory then you have to include file like **var uEntity = require('./Module/UserEntity.js');**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks a little different from how Node modules are typically written.

There's a great resource on how to write them [here](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch8.html).

You can refactor to something like this:

### UserEntity.js:

```
function User() {
  this.info = {
    'strUsername': 'Hashimoro'
  };
}

User.prototype.getInfo = function() {
  return this.info;
};

module.exports = User;
```

### app.js

```
var Person = require('./UserEntity.js');
var person = new Person();

console.log(person.info.strUsername);

// OR
console.log(person.getInfo().strUsername);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using something es6 classes it should be like that. Be a bit more explicit about the objects that you export:

**app.js**

```
var uEntity = require('./UserEntity.js');

var hm = new uEntity.person();
console.log(hm.info.strUsername);
hm.sayHello();
```

**UserEntity.js**

```
'use strict';

class User {
  constructor() {
    this.info = {
      'strUsername': 'Hashimoro'
    };
  }

  sayHello () { 
    console.log(`Username is: ${this.info.strUsername}`);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  person: User
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have not added this JSON middleware

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the `info` object also from the function.

```
    function User() {
        this.info = {
            'strUsername': 'Hashimoro'
        };

        return {
            sayHello: ()=> { console.log('Username is: ' + info.strUsername); }
,
info : this.info
        };
    }

    module.exports.person = User;
```

Comment: Oh wow perfect didn't know you had to return it ,Now i know thank you seriously :),So by returning you make it Accessible by require right?